# GWT get old and new window size

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I want old and new height, width of window on window re-size event. 
How I can do that, I am just getting new height and width on window re-size.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get old dimensions in the `ResizeEvent` received when the window size changes. But you can save old values attributes inside your `ResizeHandler`.

```
Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
  // Save old dimensions
  int oldW = Window.getClientWidth(), oldH = Window.getClientHeight(); 

  public void onResize(ResizeEvent ev) {
    // Get new dimensions
    int newW = ev.getWidth(), newH = ev.getHeight();

    // Do something with old and new dimensions
    myResizeMethod(oldW, newW, oldH, newH); 

    // Update old dimensions
    oldW = newW; oldH = newH;
  }

});
```

Additional info: `Window` class [tracks old sizes](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.java#L859) in order to fire the resize event only in case new values are different to old ones, so it will be ease to add those values to the `ResizeEvent` object. You can either request or send a patch to GWT with this feature.